# Is there a counter example for this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

I encountered this theorem:

> Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function on $(a,b)$ such that there's $M \ge  0$ and for $x \in (a,b)$, $f'(x)$ is bounded by $M$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

So the theorem itself wasn't difficult to prove. I just used the MVT:
For any $x,y \in R$ with $x<y$ the Mean-value theorem gives you a $L \in (a,b)$ such that
$f(y)−f(x)=f′(L)(y−x)$
Since $|f′(L)|<M$, it follows that
$|f(y)−f(x)|<M|y−x|$
Now for $\delta>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon/M$, then
$|x−y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)−f(y)|<\epsilon$

My question is about the other way of the theorem.

If the function was uniformly continuous then do we conclude that its derivative is bounded?

Comment: **What** theorem? You stated some hypotheses but left off the conclusion...

Comment: @lulu sorry, I edited my post

Comment: The theorem you want is this:  Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is everywhere differentiable.  Then the derivative  $f'$ is bounded if and only if $f$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous but $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is not bounded.

Comment: Ohhhhh! You know what I thought I needed to find a function that is uniformly continuous but not differentiable and its differentiation is not bounded. Thank you so much!

Comment: @HodaBibo Well it will be difficult to find the derivative of a function that is not differentiable

Comment: LOL! My brain just stopped working I was so confused, I'm sorry I bothered you with a dumb post.

Comment: @HodaBibo no problem at all. sometimes you can’t see the forrest for the trees. happens to me too a lot.

Comment: Depending on the conditions, you could still go with $\sqrt x$ on $(0,1)$.  It's still uniformly continuous, it's differentiable on the entire interval, but the derivative is not bounded.